# GUI Designer in IntelliJ unable generate a Java Class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, gui-designer

I am using IntelliJ GUI Designer to generate a GUI application (first-time-user). I tried generating some small example UI's and was able to do it. However, today which trying something, the application prompted me to provide a user name and date, which I think made changes in the package files (I suppose). And, since then, everytime when I am generating a new GUI form, it does not generate the .java file (Only the .form file is generated). And gives me the following errors.

[image]
Can someone please help me to find the error and resolve it, or is there a way to restore the original GUI Designer files in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it! Made changes in the File and Code Templates of the setting options and it worked.